# Comic that ends with two sisters fighting sea monsters on a ship in a stormy sea

Tags: story-identification, comics

For the past few weeks, I have been trying to search for a comic book that I read ages ago (maybe around 2012) but I can't seem to remember the title. I been searching the internet, going through different websites, going through my library check out history, going through "Top 100 Comic Books!" but I can't find it.

One thing I'm sure of is it being in the fantasy, adventure genre.

I remember parts of the story but not the whole plot of it. I remember where this guy tries to catch up another guy and the scene covers two whole pages and it shows the different interactions of the townspeople, there was detail, and it was a beautiful drawing.

The ending is they were on a ship and it was stormy at sea and there was a lot of chaos and fighting. Then two (I think sisters) were fighting with the people on board the ship and they were sea monsters (I have a feeling they were mermaids).

I think the art style is very detailed and with lots of colors, but not pastel or light ones, I have a feeling there's a lot of dark greens and blues. I'm not sure if I'm making this up but there's a green potion or something green that represents powers. Maybe that's the reason why the two sea monsters were fighting with the people on the ship.

Comment: Welcome to SFF.SE! You might want to take the [tour], it provides an explanation of how the site works. You' provided some useful information, but it's always helpful to [edit] in any additional information you can think of. What country did you read it in? What language was it in? Was it just a comic book (slightly smaller than a magazine), or could it have been a trade paperback (book format)? Did the story end, or did it seem like it was to be continued?

Comment: "The Wake" has sea monsters and ships...